# Illegal character in query when importing wikipedia data into Neo4j

Tags: json, neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I'm trying to reproduce a [quickgraph example](https://jbarrasa.com/2016/08/03/quickgraph2-how-is-wikipedias-knowledge-organised/) and failing with this error:

> Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.json`: Caused by:
>   java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in query at index 149:
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&list=categorymembers&cmtype=subcat&cmtitle=Category:Main_topic_classifications&cmprop=ids|title&cmlimit=500

I can visit that url in my browser and see a json, but I can't figure out which character there is illegal and why.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Java parsers that APOC uses can't deal with the `|` character, so it had to be replaced with `%7C`